# Add Class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, addclass, dom-manipulation

```
if ($("#logo-buttons-bg ul li").has("ul")){
    $(this).addClass("hide-sub-menu");
}
```

How to add **hide-sub-menu** class to each **#logo-buttons-bg ul li** that has **ul** element inside ?

Comment: For the benefit of future readers of this question: in the sample code posted above, `$(this)` does not actually refer to the elements filtered by the preceding `$()`, and the filter `.has("ul")` actually returns a [`jQuery object`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), not a boolean. See the answers below for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **[`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** selector.

```
$("#logo-buttons-bg > ul > li:has(ul)").addClass("hide-sub-menu");
```

Comment: This one is much cleaner

Answer (score 4):

This should be good:

```
$("#logo-buttons-bg ul li").has("ul").addClass("hide-sub-menu");
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has/ Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

Comment: You can also use the has selector http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/  $("#logo-buttons-bg ul li:has(ul)").addClass("hide-sub-menu");

Comment: This answer works, my doubt was in error. http://jsfiddle.net/8LsrW/ My original verification search autocompleted to the wrong jQuery function. :/

Comment: I still like tech's since it is much cleaner

Comment: I'm not a big fan of pseudo in selectors as they honestly don't look as clean to me as chaining... and they actually have been slower, atleast in cases that i've ran performance tests on.

Comment: @Huangism Honestly, I'd actually typically have done more chaining rather than less. I think of it as easier to read and in any case that I've tested - performs better... like `$("#logo-buttons-bg")find.("li").has("ul")` in this case : http://jsperf.com/has-vs-has/2

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
$('ul').filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('#logo-buttons-bg ul li').length;
}).addClass('hide-sub-menu');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

`:has`selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

try:

```
$("#logo-buttons-bg > ul > li:has(ul)").addClass("hide-sub-menu");
```

#### Explaination

use `parent>child` as it selects all the element as compare to `parent child` which select only first element, so now u targeted all the `li` has the parent `#lofo-buttons-bg`.

`:has(ul)` will check whether these li contails `ul` tag as a child if true then it will add the class.

Comment: this answer is the exact same as techfoobar's :)